# German special characters in filenames

Tags: raspbian

I followed this [Tutorial](https://medium.com/@aallan/adding-an-external-disk-to-a-raspberry-pi-and-sharing-it-over-the-network-5b321efce86a) to use a external HDD as file system in my local network. I followed the tutorial for the AFS network drive, because currently I'm only using MacOS. Now I can access the files from my Mac and add new files. In the tutorial FAT32 was used, I used exFAT instead. The problem is that german special characters like ä,ö,ü are not allowed in the filename.

My `fstab` file contains the following string:

`/dev/sda1 /mnt/datacenter auto defaults,user,umask=000 0 1`

I used `umask=000`, because my pi user had no permission to change files. So with the umask I can change files and directories directly after booting.

The localisation settings of the pi are set to german and the charset is set to UTF-8. What setting do I need to change that these characters are allowed in the filename?

On the Mac I get an error from finder that the file can not be created and I should use other characters. Also when I move a file with one of the characters to the network drive I get an error with `Error -50` On the PI I also get an error that the filename is not allowed.

UPDATE:

I have checked the drive again and it seems like the formating of the drive was not correct. On MacOS the drive was shown as one external drive in the Disk Utilitis. On the PI I used `fdisk` to look at the partitions of the drive and the larger partition was not formated correctly. After formating the drive again and checking the results with `fdisk` I'm able to create files and directories with the special characters.

Comment: @TomasBy ups that didn't work. Here is the [link](https://medium.com/@aallan/adding-an-external-disk-to-a-raspberry-pi-and-sharing-it-over-the-network-5b321efce86a)

Comment: @TomasBy I used the Disk Utility on my Mac to format the drive as exFAT.

Comment: Welcome.  But you need to clarify what you mean by "german special characters like ä,ö,ü are not allowed in the filename".  According to wikipedia, that should be okay for exFAT.  *So **when and where exactly** are you encountering this problem?* In other words, why do you think special characters aren't allowed?  What are you doing specifically with the filesystem?  Creating files on the pi and you aren't allowed?  Or are filenames appearing differently on different machines?  Etc.  It is hard to see based on this where the actual problem is.

Comment: If the problem happens on the Mac and the filesystem was created with the Mac, then you should inquire about this on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) instead of here.  If it was created using the Pi, you should include exactly how you did that (not just a link to a tutorial), and the output of `sudo fdisk -l [/dev/whatever]` on the device containing the filesystem.

Comment: That you get the same error on both the Mac and the Pi suggests it is not a Pi issue. You can try formatting the external drive differently (as NTFS or as FAT32 on a PC for example). Generally, using "native" file system tends to work better (HFS on Mac, NTFS/FAT on PC...).

Comment: Good read: [Wikipedia: Comparison of filename limitations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Comparison_of_filename_limitations), [The Open Group: Portable Filename Character Set](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_282), [Stanford University: Best practices for file naming](https://library.stanford.edu/research/data-management-services/data-best-practices/best-practices-file-naming)

Comment: @TomasBy okey I changed the settings for the folder so that files will not moved to trash and will get deleted directly. Now it works as expected.

Comment: Please make your UPDATE an answer and accept it after three days. This will finish your question and show others that it has an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked the drive again and it seems like the formating of the drive was not correct. On MacOS the drive was shown as one external drive in the Disk Utilitis. On the PI I used fdisk to look at the partitions of the drive and the larger partition was not formated correctly. After formating the drive again and checking the results with fdisk I'm able to create files and directories with the special characters.